# Weird experience with C++ preIncrement and postIncrement

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

`++a = b` operation is showing no error but `a++ = b` is showing error while compiling with `g++`. Both the variable are initialized before these operations.

Although these operation have no practical usage I think both of them should issue the same error while compiling. What do you think? If there is a valid reason kindly explain to me. Thanks in advance! :)

P.S. `gcc` gives error on both of these.

Comment: Why do you think those expressions should give the same error? They are quite different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let see how declarations of pre/post-increment look like ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec ):

```
++a: T& operator ++(T& a);
a++: T operator ++(T& a, int);
```

And you've got the answer - preInc returns reference, so you can override "a" variable using "=" operator.

Answer (score 6):

The result if `++a` is an *Lvalue*, but the result of `a++` is an *Rvalue*, you can't assign anything to an *Rvalue*, hence the error.

The difference is that (simplifying a bit)  an *Lvalue* is an expression that refers to some object, while an *Rvalue* refers to the *data* stored somewhere in the memory.

Let's say the result of `a++` is `7`. Basically, when you write `a++ = b;` you are trying to assign `b` to `7` which is clearly not possible. 
When you write `++a = b;`, on the other hand, the result of the increment is an *Lvalue* that refers to `a`, so the assignment will be valid.

You can read more about *Lvalues* and *Rvalues* [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/lvalue.htm).

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated than that. Rvalues of class-type refer to objects, too. An Xvalue is also an Rvalue and always refers to some object. Only PRvalues of scalar types are just values and don't refer to any objects.

Comment: @sellibitze, yes, also most objects can be used as both lvalues and rvalues, because an lvalue can be implicitly converted to an rvalue, but not vice versa. I didn't put too much details though, because they are not _directly_ relevant to the question, so I placed a link in case the OP would like to read further.

Comment: "the result of the increment is a temporary which holds 7" -- no, the result of the increment is an lvalue expression that refers to the object `a` (whose value is 1 greater than it was before the increment). There's no temporary.

Answer (score 3):

`++a` is an **l-value** (increments `a` and "returns" the new value), `a++` is an **r-value** (increments `a` and "returns" a temporary with the old value of `a`).

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is not code that makes much sense, but I would say that `++a` increments a and yields the value of the incremented variable, while `a++` yields the lvalue of the variable and then increments a (which is then overwritten by the assignment). You can not assign to the value of a, you need an lvalue (which is basically a value that has an associated memory allocated).